# Augmented reality applications without markers

Tags: augmented-reality

I had done augmented reality using markers .I just wonder if any AR Applications can be done without the help of markers .For example using any image / capturing live video and integrating the virtual object in the real world using any buttons ..
Is this possible If so can anyone  please help me do the process .. It will be great help to me

Answer (score 9):

There are a couple of natural feature tracking libraries becoming available now: the Qualcomm AR SDK and Metaio Unifeye SDK and Metaio Junaio Glue all allow you to register and track an image on mobile devices, and HIT Lab NZ has the Opira library which provides similar functionality but on desktop (with really nice authoring tools).

There are two main approaches to inserting a 3D object into an unprepared, unmodelled videostream: the first is to do some variation on SLAM (simultaneous location and mapping) - find feature points in the videostream, detect the ones that are robust frame-to-frame, and use those to build a 3D map of points, which can be used as an environment/tracking model for inserting your 3D object. The most famous in AR circles is [PTAM](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gk/PTAM/) (parallel tracking and mapping). The second approach is mostly used outdoors: assume the user will stay still, and ask them to generated a panorama, which you project onto a cylinder around the user. Then objects can be inserted into coordinates around the cylinder, and the environment can be learned and tracked. This is [Panoramic Tracking and Mapping](http://studierstube.icg.tugraz.at/handheld_ar/panomt.php) (confusingly, the same acronym).

Hope this helps you get started!

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply .I will keep updating the process cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can try Sony SmartAR SDK witch implement AR without markers, including high speed camera and large scale. Unfortunately the project looks abandoned. The documentation will be found in the downloaded zip file.

https://www.sonydna.com/sdna/solution/SmartAR_SDK.html

And here is an incredible demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XCEp7udJ2n4

Even better, there is an updated markless AR SDK called Kudan: https://www.kudan.eu/features/

You have the option to use the Unity 3D package.

Answer (score 0):

This is a field of ongoing research. As far as I know, there are no known robust (and fast) algorithms yet. Maybe you can find some inspiration on [CV Papers](http://www.cvpapers.com).